# Who is Annie Bellis?

Tags: georges-secret-key-to-the-universe

In the book *[George’s Secret Key to the Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1111741.George_s_Secret_Key_to_the_Universe)* by Lucy Hawking, who is Annie Bellis?

Comment: I don't think the characters of Eric and Annie are based on anyone in particular. Lucy Hawking name checks *Eric Simonoff* and *Annie Eaton* in the acknowledgements, though whether she got the character names from them I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annie Bellis is the scientist Eric's daughter. When Eric first meets George, he introduces himself as Annie's dad:

> "I live next door," George went on by way of explanation. "But my pig escaped through a hole in the fence so I had to come and get him."
>
> "Of course!" The man smiled. "I was wondering how you got into the kitchen. My name is Eric – **I'm Annie’s dad**." He pointed to the blonde girl.
>
> "Annie’s dad?" said George slyly, smiling at the girl. She stuck her nose up in the air and refused to meet his eye.
>
> <sub>*George's Secret Key to the Universe* - Chapter Two</sub>

Interstingly, the surname "Bellis" is not mentioned in the first book at all. We only find out Annie and Eric's last name in the first chapter of the second book, *George's Cosmic Treasure Hunt*:

> "Come as your favourite space object," he’d been told by **Eric Bellis**, the scientist next door [...]
>
> <sub>*George's Cosmic Treasure Hunt* - Chapter One</sub>